# Module 'YoVapriikissaBox2d:core:1.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar

I am having some problems with gradle using Android Studio.

I've added a dependency under  `project(":android")` and a repository under 
    `allprojects`

The problem I'm having now is that I get the error

> Module 'YoVapriikissaBox2d:core:1.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar

when I resync gradle. I'm fairly new to Android Studio so I have no clue on how to go about resolving the issue.

The repository I'm trying to use is the following:
https://github.com/controlwear/virtual-joystick-android

I would really appreciate some help as I need a virtual joystick for the project I'm working on.